# How to save and retrieve data from sdcard or database in android?

Tags: android

I'm building an app that retrieves image of the day from Nasa website.

It basically has 3 `TextViews` to display title, date and description of the app and an `ImageView` to display bitmap image from website. And the app works fine.

But I want to add the ability to view these data even when the app is offline and to show previous image along with 3 `TextViews` onSwipe or onClick...

Can anybody please help me with this? 
I've tried searching on how save and retrieve strings but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or if you plan to store more data try a [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html). Here is the [tutorial to store files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) in Android.

Comment: Thanks a loy AlexVogel.. It helped a lot.. I'll post the results soon.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is better than Official Docs

```
[http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html][1]
```